# Where in the filesystem are settings saved? Namely ADB backup password

Tags: root-access, file-system, shell

Where in the phone filesystem are settings saved? I've lost my ADB backup password and simply want to delete it. If it affects other settings that won't matter too much.

I will be interfacing the filesystem through a root shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my stock Android 4.2.1 the file responsible for holding Desktop backup password seems to be `/data/backup/pwhash`.

I took a backup of it, renamed it, restarted the device, and the password was reset to empty. Now I could create a new password from the **Settings** easily.

In CM12, I had to rename two files, namely `pwhash` and `pwversion`, and everything went well after a reboot.

**Note**: I noticed file modification in `/data/<FOLDERS>` to proceed and ultimately reach my conclusion, which of course works here.

Comment: As for most of the settings, `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db` contains the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Moto X Play (6.0.1), stock ROM, unrooted and may be of use to others

I wanted to remove the password set earlier for a different reason

In USB configuration, I entered the previous password, in *Enter your current full backup password* and left **blank** in both *Enter a new password for full backup here* and *Re-enter your new full backup password here* and clicked on <kbd>Set Backup Password</kbd> and it accepted it meaning that I didn't have a backup password now !

I verified this running [Helium chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/helium-backup/gpglbgbpeobllokpmeagpoagjbfknanl?hl=en) which requires backup password to be **blank** and it worked