# Transfer apps and data from a rooted phone to a phone without root

Tags: adb, backup, restore, data-transfer

I used to use TitaniumBackup to transfer apps and data from one Android phone to another when both devices are rooted. Recently I got a phone which currently does not have root access, so TitaniumBackup would not be useful. Most apps are not an issue, but I have trouble transferring a few apps and their data.

I was thinking to use adb, and tried using "adb backup -f appname.ab -apk app_package_name" on the old (and rooted) phone, but got the following error:

> Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation.

The strange thing is that there is nothing there for me to accept when I unlock the phone or when I keep the phone unlocked. Someone also had the same problem [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/147606/adb-backup-on-marshmallow-is-it-different).

Any suggestions as to how to handle the transfer? Any better alternatives?

Comment: What happens when you unlock your device and accept the backup? That's not an 'error' message.

Comment: @bmdixon Sorry I forgot to mention that there is nothing there for me to accept when I unlock the phone or when I keep the phone unlocked. I saw someone in another place having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your command and in the logcat an error was given "no backup packages supplied and neither -shared nor -all given" so I assume you are missing some parameters.

I tried the following command "adb backup -all" and the backup window successfully popped up. My advise is to check your logcat or modify your adb parameters. As per this [post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-phone-backup-unlock-root-t1420351) the command

> adb backup -apk -shared -all -f c:\backup20111230.ab

should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I meant to backup just one specific app with command  "adb backup -f appname.ab -apk app_package_name" . However, even with your suggestion of backing up all apps via "adb backup -apk -shared -all -f all.ab", I still get the message: Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation. And this happens on two computers I have tried so far. Very weird.

Comment: @bluepole Check your logcat. There are plenty free apps to do that. Without that we won't be able to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Thanks! What should I look for in the huge text file? Any keyword like 'adb'?

Comment: I just tried another phone, and had no problem with the adb backup command. So the problem seems to be with this particular phone (LG G2 with root). Is the logcat structured in a backward order in time?

Comment: @bluepole just issue the command and check the latest logcat right after. It should be of type "error".  Different apps may list them in different order, but I think there must be an exact time for each log.