# Android adb restore not working on Android 8.1.0 as target phone

Tags: adb, 4.4-kitkat, backup, restore, 8.1-oreo

I'm **migrating app data** involving **several** packages, using `adb backup` and `restore`, from an older phone (source) to a newer phone (target). Android versions are detailed below. I'm using the following procedure for each one of them:

**1.** Generate a backup file on source phone:

**a)** Alternative: with apk

```
C:\>adb devices
...
C:\>adb backup -f com.example.package.ab -apk com.example.package
```

**b)** Alternative: without apk

```
C:\>adb backup -f com.example.package.ab com.example.package
```

**2.** Restore backup file on target phone:

**a)** Alternative: with apk

```
C:\>adb devices
...
C:\>adb restore com.example.package.ab
```

**b)** Alternative: without apk (installing clean app first)

```
C:\>adb restore com.example.package.ab
```

*Note:* The package name listed is obfuscated as `com.example.package`.

Android version are: **4.4.4** on source phone and **8.1.0** on target phone.

After following these steps for each package, I get no app(s) present on my target phone, with no error messages at all (just a "finished"-like toast notification is shown). However, I managed to dump some error messages regarding app restore process via `adb logcat` on the target phone that might be interesting and/or helpful. They follow:

**a)** Alternative: with apk

```
C:\>adb logcat

03-31 19:14:58.478  2050 26649 I BackupManagerService: Package com.example.package not installed; requiring apk in dataset
03-31 19:14:58.478  2050 26649 D BackupManagerService: Installing from backup: com.example.package
03-31 19:15:01.528 26665 26678 W asset   : Asset path /data/cache/backup_stage/com.example.package is neither a directory nor file (type=0).
03-31 19:15:01.529 26665 26678 W DefContainer: Failed to parse package at /data/cache/backup_stage/com.example.package: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/cache/backup_stage/com.example.package
```

**b)** Alternative: without apk

```
C:\>adb logcat

03-31 20:08:45.154  2050 30170 D BackupManagerService: Need to launch agent for com.example.package
03-31 20:08:45.155  2050 30170 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.example.package appid=10155 user=0: clear data
03-31 20:08:45.157  2050  2096 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.example.package appid=10155 user=-1: clearApplicationUserData
03-31 20:08:45.160  2050 30170 I ConditionProviders: Disallowing condition provider com.example.package
03-31 20:08:45.283  2723  2723 I GeofencerStateMachine: removeGeofences: removeRequest=RemoveGeofencingRequest[REMOVE_ALL packageName=com.example.package]
03-31 20:08:45.300  2050 30170 I ActivityManager: Start proc 30204:com.example.package/u0a155 for backup android/FullBackupAgent
03-31 20:08:45.300  2050 30170 D BackupManagerService: awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{455f3d3 com.example.package}
03-31 20:08:45.352  2050 11378 D BackupManagerService: agentConnected pkg=com.example.package agent=android.os.BinderProxy@c07c18e
03-31 20:08:45.607  3020  7675 I Icing   : doRemovePackageData com.example.package
03-31 20:08:51.277  2050 30170 D BackupManagerService: Invoking agent to restore file code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.package-2.apk.classes2.dex
03-31 20:08:51.426  2050 30170 D BackupManagerService: Invoking agent to restore file code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.example.package-2.apk.classes2.zip
03-31 20:08:52.024  2050  5655 I ActivityManager: Process com.example.package (pid 30204) has died: cch+4CEM
```

I want to mention some additional considerations about my phone configuration which might be causing some trouble:

- Both my older and newer phone are not rooted and I don't want them to be.
- I'm not sure if I'm using the right "ADB Interface" controller on my Windows desktop (under Device Manager).
- My target phone is encrypted.
- Is it necessary to have "unknown sources" enabled to make `adb restore` to work? (I can't remember I needed it on other backup/restore operations regarding different phones than the mentioned ones on this question. Of course, Developer Options are enabled on both phones.)
- I'm not sure if I'm using a version of `adb` Windows executable that is compatible with my target phone Android version.

So, after reminding that I previously used this procedure between other combinations of source/target Android versions (for example: from *ICS* to *KitKat*) and it worked right, *my question is:* **Is there any way to get this backup procedure work between the mentioned versions of Android (source/target)?** If the answer is "no"; **why?** and: **do other methods not involving `adb backup` and `restore` exist to achieve the same goal: Google Drive, third party apps, manufacturer specific apps, etc...?** (Note: Absolutely **I'd rather use adb backup/restore** whenever it's possible.)

Related or similar questions I've found follow:
[Applications are not installed with adb restore](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169534/applications-are-not-installed-with-adb-restore)
[adb backup on Marshmallow - is it different?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/147606/adb-backup-on-marshmallow-is-it-different/150452#150452)

**Final note:** Sorry if I used some bad translated user interface messages or strings, since I don't use English language on either my Android devices or Windows desktop.

Comment: I do remember a backup file format change especially regarding the encryption. May be it helps to unpack and then repack the backup data using [adb backup extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor)

Comment: Try first installing the `.apk` itself, and restore the backup afterwards. That's a known bug with Android 7 IIRC which might still be open with some Android 8 devices. The [`tools` folder](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar/tree/master/tools) of my Adebar gives you the needed helpers for Linux/Mac and Cygwin: you'd want `abrestore` for your purpose (it extracts the `.apk` from the backup, installs it, and then restores the backup). Let me know if that did the job, so I can write up an answer.

Comment: and of course, not mentioned already, test backup & restore single app from/to same target phone 8.1 is working in general. latest adb https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads

Comment: I achieved restoring a single package this way: using ADB 1.0.31 to create the backup from Android 4.4.4 and using ADB 1.0.41 (got from [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/)) to restore it to Android 8.1.0. Both are Windows executables. I need to do a little more testing before ensure it works for every package. Should I post a self-answer after doing that?