# Trying to perform ADB Backup but it prompts for a password

Tags: adb, backup, htc

I am trying to perform an ADB backup but I got stuck at the step where the phone receives the request of backup from the computer (the command I used on ADB was
 `adb backup -apk -shared -all -f F:\Android backup.ab`).

It is asking for a password as in the pic below (sorry my phone is in Chinese, I will translate the dialogue below):

'The system has received a request to backup all data to the computer; do you allow this action?

If you did not request to do so, please do not allow this action.

Your phone has been encrypted, therefore you must encrypt your backup. Please enter password below:'

I actually forgot that I ever encrypted my phone; and I certainly don't remember having set a password for the encryption (I use the unlocking pattern in daily operations). So I thought this is to set a password for the backup action.

But as you can see, I typed some words in, but the 'Backup your data' at the bottom right button just wouldn't respond no matter how many times I pressed it. (I pressed the 'Do not backup' button next to it and it quit instantly, so I am sure the screen is reacting to my touch alright)

Would anyone mind lending a hand please? Thank you so much!

[image]
 <sup>Click on the image to enlarge the image</sup>

Comment: If have seen devices where the backup app was defect. On the adb shell execute `/system/bin/bu backup` if it throws an error backup is defect on your device.

Comment: @Robert Hi Robert so I am new to both ADB and this forum so please bear with me; when you mention adb shell, do you mean the cmd.exe I type the backup command in? Because that line of command doesn't seem to work

Comment: I think I have a lock pattern set for the encryption instead of a password because everytime I power the phone on it only asks for the pattern - so is that what is it asking for here? I don't see a pattern entering function though

Comment: See if answers here help https://android.stackexchange.com/q/96892/131553

Comment: Learning the capabilities of `adb` and it's shell is always a good idea. For more details search android.stackexchange.com and the Internet for `adb` and/or `adb shell` and you will find dozen of tutorials.