# adb backup command on non-rooted device creates an empty backup file?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb, backup, usb-debugging, motorola-moto-g2

I recently tried to backup my Motorola Moto G2 XT1068 phone running Lollipop 5.0.1 and after connecting it over USB with usb-debugging ON and I ran the adb backup command to backup my device completely and this question [Full backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) and [the solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28315/27149) guided me. However running the following adb command,

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all -system -f D:/backup.ab
```

din't work in my case. The command instructed me to Unlock my device and confirm the backup operation. However doing so displayed the `Backup started` and `Backup completed` toast message back to back in just one second duration. And obviously the `backup.ab` file generated too was an empty 0kb file.

Removing and changing the parameter din't help either.

Comment: I had a similar problem on a 4.4.2 device, but your solution does not work for some reason... although it had worked before.. curious.

Comment: @jpaugh Try this answer http://android.stackexchange.com/q/83080/96277 which is specifically for KitKat.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The workaround was to ***set the desktop backup password*** under Developer settings. It seems there is a bug in backup process. If you didn't set a desktop backup password under the developer options settings the above problems occur and your backup will eventually be incomplete(empty backup file). However, I couldn't find an official source for this bug report that setting the desktop backup password solves adb backup issue.

Got this information based on the [XDA Forum [GUIDE] Full Phone Backup without Unlock or Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-phone-backup-unlock-root-t1420351)

> Note: There seems to be a bug in which backup and restore operations will
>   fail unless a desktop backup password is set under Developer Options.
>   It will not work with a blank password.

After I set my desktop backup password under

`Settings > Developer Options > Desktop backup password`

`adb backup -apk -shared -all -f D:/backup.ab`

I am now able to run the above adb backup commands successfully. Note that I left the `-system` parameter as it is default one and the `backup.ab` file is almost 6GB now.

Comment: Did you check whether a bug has been filed? Your answer is at odds with this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/83080/96277) (for Kitkat though).

Comment: @Firelord No I couldn't find a bug reported on this issue. But I don't remember encrypting or set my desktop backup password earlier. I input 1234 in current password field and luckily it accepted. :)

Comment: Good to have this, so thanks for sharing – but it's a work-around at best (not a "solution"). Sometimes one needs to have the backups without password encryption (e.g. to convert the `.ab` file to a `.tar` for investigation).

Comment: @Izzy But Android Backup Extractor can convert the `.ab` into `.tar` even if the file is encrypted with a password. Of course, you've to supply the password during conversion. :)

Comment: Might be – still makes things a bit more complicated :) Just saying, no criticizing intended!