# 'adb backup -apk -shared -all -f "D:\backup.ab' initiates backup, completes, but produces a file that is only 1kb

Tags: adb, backup

I'm attempting to backup my old Android device, a Samsung Galaxy S3, so that I can lend it to my friend while his is away at repairs, then restore it when he's done with it.

I have the Samsung USB drivers installed, and the device is recognised.

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
4df7f9574edecf7f        device
```

I set a developer password, as per [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116439/adb-backup-command-on-non-rooted-device-creates-an-empty-backup-file), which caused the "Backup starting..." to last about 3 seconds longer than before. It completes successfully, then produces a file that is 1kb.

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb backup -all -f D:\backup.ab
Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation.

C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>
```

[image]

Does anybody know what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe using an earlier version of `adb` works for you too, see this question [ADB backup creates 0-byte file; prompts for current backup password even though I never set one; "Failed to set password" for Desktop backup password](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/83080/44466)

Comment: This thread maybe the answer for your problem too: [adb backup command on non-rooted device creates an empty backup file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116439/adb-backup-command-on-non-rooted-device-creates-an-empty-backup-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try with more parameters, like:

```
adb backup -all -apk -obb -shared -nosystem -f "yourFile.ab"
```

*Unless you have a rooted phone, I don't recommend `-system`. Use `-nosystem` instead.