# adb backup finishes without saving data

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, backup, nexus-4, macos

I'm using a rooted Google Nexus 4 (mako) with CyanogenMod 11 and adb 1.0.32 on OS X.
I also use disk encryption.

adbd is running as root.
I'm trying to create a full backup using:

```
adb backup -apk -obb -shared -all -nosystem
```

However, regardless of the options passed to `adb backup`, it asks me to enter my backup password on the phone and then exists, showing `Backup finished` on the phone.
It only leaves a 549 bytes `backup.ab` file.

Using the wrong or no backup password does the same but leaves a 0 bytes file.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the question has been answered at [ADB backup creates 0-byte file; prompts for current backup password even though I never set one; "Failed to set password" for Desktop backup password](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83080/adb-backup-creates-0-byte-file-prompts-for-current-backup-password-even-though?rq=1)

The solution is to revert to android-platform-tools 19.0.1 which bring adb 1.0.31, backups are working with that version.