# Backup apps and data using adb

Tags: backup

I wanted to backup all the apps and the data of my phone, before I do some hazardous things on it.

I have run:

```
./adb backup -f /mydir/backup.file -apk -obb -shared -all -system
```

But the resulting file is ridiculously small (549 bytes), so I know it has not backuped everything.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Hard to say (but yes, I'd expect a file of several GB, with all your eggs in one basket). You could try to `adb logcat -v time | tee logcat.txt` (Ctrl-C when current timestamp is reached) and see if you find some pointers. Were there any errors shown? Have you been asked to confirm the backup on your device?

Comment: Yes I have been asked for confirmation on my device, as well as a password for encyption. I'm gonna try logcat.

Comment: @Izzy no obvious clue in logcat... it is not even mentionning the backup operation...

Comment: That's strange. As you've entered a password for encryption, those 549 bytes are obviously nothing but the (encrypted and compressed) backup header (without password and for a single app, that's usually 41 bytes). No idea what goes wrong there, but maybe you try to keep the ball low and just backup a single *user* app first, to see whether that works? E.g. `adb backup -f backup.ab -apk com.foobar.app` (replacing `com.foobar.app` with the package name of one user app you've installed)?

Comment: @Izzy that worked much better. I will try to find which combination of flags makes the backup fail. ( I have not tried the restore yet, but the file is several MByte big, that's much better)

Comment: Start with skipping `-system` (what do you want with the system `.apk`s?) and `-shared` (SD card content you can copy separately). I'd recommend a "complete" backup (APK+data) from all your apps (one backup file per app – my little tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) can help you with that as it e.g. creates the script for it), data-only backups from system apps (Adebar's script include that), and the "shared" you can do separately by simply copying the SD card. Leaves the `-obb` I forgot to integrate with Adebar – but you can "RegEx-Replace" that into the scripts).

Comment: maybe try adb of an older version? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83080/adb-backup-creates-0-byte-file-prompts-for-current-backup-password-even-though