# Backup data with broken screen and empty system

Tags: adb, data-recovery, twrp, clockworkmod-recovery, broken-screen

Device details:

- Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300) with broken screen
- No System (was running CM13.0 with GAPPS)
- Currently flashed with TWRP 3.1 with Odin (was CWM)
- /data | /dev/block/mmcblk0p12 | Size: 11622MB Used: 5540MB Free: 3440MB Backup Size: 5540MB

System details:

- Windows 10
- adb-1.0.39

I need to make a valid nandroid or adb backup for Titanium Backup Pro on my new device. What I've tried so far:

- adb backup --twrp data (also with --compress option) to my laptop but it's currently unrestorable. [#1011](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/1011)
- adb backup without --twrp, results in 0KB file. Tried using adb-1.0.31 as described at [question 83080](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83080/adb-backup-creates-0-byte-file-prompts-for-current-backup-password-even-though) but didn't work (no password set)
- backup with CM Recovery v6.0.4.6, but seems to fail on system (not sure). The backup folder only contains boot.img and recovery.img
- adb uninstall package to create space/reduce backup size. /sbin/sh: pm: not found

Any other ways I can try without losing apps+data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restored system with what was running before by doing:

- twrp wipe system (it was already empty, but for good measure)
- twrp wipe cache
- twrp install /sdcard/Download/cm-13.0-20160113-UNOFFICIAL-temasek-i9300-V2.9.zip
- twrp install /sdcard/Download/open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini-20171004.zip
- twrp install /sdcard/TWRP/SR4-SuperSU-v2.78-SYSTEMMODE.zip
- twrp fixperms
- twrp wipe cache
- twrp wipe dalvik

Aftwards it got stuck in a bootloop. I had Android Studio open to watch the logcat and somehow managed to **adb shell pm uninstall** packages, just before the Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) error, with the intention to fix the bootloop.

I uninstalled CM 13 themes first as they where appearing before the Fatal signal 11. It got to a point where it was unclear what was causing the bootloop and remembered I had activated a custom bootanimation with one of those themes. [Deleted the /data/system/theme/bootanimation.zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/cm12-theme-engine-howto-recover-boot-t3021505), but did not help. 
Tried [adding debug.sf.nobootanimation=1 to the /system/build.prop](https://www.theandroidsoul.com/edit-build-prop-without-root-using-adb-in-twrp-recovery/), but did not help either.

Then I decided to uninstall packages I don't need backing up, as I was planning to try and create a backup again with CWM Recovery when enough space was available. To my surprise I was able to get out of the bootloop! Probably one or more apps were the cause of the bootloop after re-flashing the ROM.

I am now able to use Vysor to backup apps+data I need with Titanium Backup to transfer to my new device.

Alhamdulillah..

I hope this may be of use to someone else who may be experiencing a similar problem.

Options are:

- Create nandroid or adb backup with [TWRP](https://twrp.me/) or CWM Recovery, [for Samsung Galaxy S2/S3/S4/S5 available here](http://nowandroid.net/install-cwm-recovery-samsung-galaxy-s2s3s4s5/)
- Restore ROM without losing data

  - View device screen on Desktop (e.g. [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io))
  - Create backup of apps (e.g. [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup))